# Tipping over objects on a frictionless surface

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, torque

Is there any way you can topple over a rod which is standing up on a frictionless surface?

Comment: Yes. Imagine free falling with a vertical rod, you can rotate the rod, can't you? A force applied to one end will create a pivot about the centre of mass.

Comment: Well I asked a similar question before on stack exchange, and someone answered that it is impossible to tip over the object by applying a force to the top end of the rod.

Comment: Got a link to it?  Is it possible that the phrasing in the question was different?

Comment: Even easier, if you're not constrained to a single point of force application: push East at the top and West at the bottom of the rod.

Answer (score 2):

The best way at least for me to think about this problem is first imagine the rod in space, free from any forces including gravity. In space the rod will only rotate if a force is exerted that is not through the center of mass. Now down to earth.

To tip the rod you need a moment as you needed in space, or rather a force couple across some moment arm. Gravity presses the rod downward (and not free falling as suggested) , and assume first the force you apply is perfectly horizontal through the rod's center of mass, and the surface on which the rod stands is perfectly frictionless, then there is no couple and you cannot topple the rod.

But offset the force from the center of mass and you will have a couple. In that case if the force that can create a torque that can overcome any moments created by tilting the rod over-center, you may be able to topple the rod.

Although there is no friction the contact surface between the rod and supporting surface do play a roll in the stability. As the rod rotates there is a restoring force caused by gravity. A wider base would require a larger torque to overcome the constraint. It gets tricky because as the rod tips the center of mass rises slightly above its rest position. When the center of gravity is over the point of rotation the restoring force vanishes and the rod is unstable in the gravitational field. Without friction the balance of torque , the rods moment of inertia and geometry are all that matters and the rod will only completely topple if the torque is large enough to cause the center of mass to first reach then rotate over the contact pivot point which will be constantly sliding horizontally along the surface. IN other words there will be translation and rotation.

Comment: will applying the impulse to the top of the rod work (obviously the bottom works).

Comment: @JoshuaBenabou Note I've edited and removed 'impulse' and am speaking in terms of torque now.

Comment: Actually you can apply the force at the center of mass I think.

Comment: @JoshuaBenabou  Do you mean for your particular problem you are constrained to apply the force through the center of mass? If so - no rotation, no toppling. In my answer I've tried to address both situations.